# checkbox click event fired twice for class name vs once for id (jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, checkbox

I have the following piece of code running in a snippets plugin in wordpress.

Jquery:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(event)
    {
        jQuery(".checkbox").click(function()
        {
            if(jQuery(this).is(":checked"))
                alert('checked');
            else
                alert('unchecked ');
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="checkbox">
      <h2>
          <label>
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="">
              Ignore Registration
          </label>
      </h2>
</div>
```

When the checkbox is checked, i received two alerts (checked, followed by unchecked).

When the checkbox is unchecked, i received two alerts as well (unchecked, and unchecked).

I'm not sure why this is happening, but when i changed the input tag to use the id instead of class, the solution works perfectly.

```
jQuery("#checkbox").click ..........

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"..........
```

Am just trying to find out whats happening, or the difference in using classes and ids for the click event

Comment: You got your answers but a hint: it’s a good convention to prefix classnames that are used for javascript interactions with ’js-’. So giving the input the class ’js-checkbox’ would make it clearer to see what the class is meant for.

Comment: yup, agreed, point noted, will stick to some form of convention to prevent this in future, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Issue:-*** Since div and checkbox both share same class, that's why event trigger two times (clicking on checkbox trigger event on checkbox as well as on div both due to the same class)

So change the classes and you will good to go

***Working snippet:-***

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function(event) {

  jQuery(".checkbox").click(function() {

    if(jQuery(this).is(":checked"))
      alert('checked');

    else
      alert('unchecked ');


  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="">Ignore
  Registration</label></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your div class and checkbox class are same. change the div class name.

```
 <div class="checkbox1">
  <h2><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="">Ignore Registration</label></h2>
</div>
```

otherwise change in click selector

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function(event) {

    jQuery(".checkbox input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {

        if(jQuery(this).is(":checked"))
            alert('checked');

        else
            alert('unchecked ');

    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have two DOM elements with the class: `checkbox`. So your div when clicked will run the function, and your input will run the function when clicked (I'm assuming you're clicking the input which causes the function to run twice). You need to separate your HTML better, recommended is:

```
<div class="checkbox-container">
    <label>Ignore Registration</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="">
</div
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because both the `div` and the `input` have the class of `checkbox`. So when targeting this class, it is actually running against both elements.

The div is always returns unchecked, and the checkbox will return checked or unchecked respectively.

Change the class of the `div`, or change your JS to target `$(input.checkbox)` if you want to stick with the existing classnames.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
            $("#checkbox").click(function () {
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

                    if(jQuery(this).is(":checked"))
                        alert('checked');
  } else {
                   alert('unchecked ');
}
            });
        }); 

        </script>


        <form>

        <div class="checkbox">
          <h2><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id ="checkbox" value="">Ignore Registration</label></h2>
    </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: you should always add an explanation, this only leads to a copy-and-paste generation of developer :)

Answer (score 0):

I is because you have two elements with class `checkbox`. Change class in `div` surrounding your `checkbox` and it works properly.

```js
$(document).ready(function(event) {

  $(".checkbox").click(function() {

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      alert('checked');
    } else {
      alert('unchecked ');
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxContainer">
  <h2><label for="checkboxId">Ignore Registration</label>
    <input id="checkboxId" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value=""></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change the class name, In the below code there are 2 class is used with same name 1. div class :checkbox 2 is input class : checkbox, please change the div class name, then you get only 1 alert, You can add input in jQuery click functional as well

```
jQuery("input.checkbox").click(function(e) {

<div class="checkbox">
  <h2><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="">Ignore Registration</label></h2>
```

Solution 1 :

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function(event) {
    jQuery("input.checkbox").click(function() {
            if(jQuery(this).is(":checked"))
                alert('checked');

            else
                alert('unchecked ');


    });

});
</script>
<div class="checkbox">
<h2><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="">Ignore 
Registration</label></h2>
 </div>
```

Solution 2 :

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function(event) {

    jQuery(".checkbox").click(function() {

            if(jQuery(this).is(":checked"))
                alert('checked');

            else
                alert('unchecked ');


    });

});

</script>
<div class="checkbox1">
  <h2><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="">Ignore Registration</label></h2>
</div>
```